# Shading with polar curves when using tikzfillbetween

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, polarplot

I am currently trying to depict a portion of a ring which got distorted at one point. To this end, first I am plotting two curves into polar coordinates, then I am using `tikzfillbetween` command between these two paths.

Here is the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

% packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

% parameters
\def\clr{7}       % clearance
\def\pen{-6.}     % negative penetration
\def\fz{0.625}    % fake zero
\def\nl{2}        % number of lobes
\def\wl{0.18}     % width of lobes
\def\th{0.3}      % thickness

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    % bottom path A
    \draw [line width=1.4pt,,color=black!50,domain=0.3*pi:0.7*pi,samples=256,smooth, name path=A] plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x r,radius= {\clr-(\clr+\pen)*exp(-((\x - (pi/\nl))/\wl)^2))});
    % top path B
    \draw [thick,color=black!50,domain=0.3*pi:0.7*pi,samples=256,smooth, name path=B] plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x r,radius= {\th + \clr-(\clr+\pen)*exp(-((\x - (pi/\nl))/\wl)^2))});
    
    \tikzfillbetween[of=A and B]{color=gray!50};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the current output:

[image: ring]

**Question**: How one can add some kind of shading between these curves (that is not really radial) so that it fades away when it goes from inner path to outer path gradually?

Expected output should look like below *but curved like the above picture*:

```
\draw[line width=1.4pt,color=black!50,name path=A] (0,0) -- (12,0);
\draw[thick,color=black!50,name path=B] (0,0.5) -- (12,0.5);
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B]{bottom color = gray!50, top color= gray!5};
```

[image: output]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How should it look like at the end? Can you show an exemplaric image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this is to use a 3D plot for the shading. We set the domain of the radius to go from 0 to your thickness (`\th`). Then plot your curve across this radius while increasing the `z` coordinate as we go.

This produces a conical kind of shape. Then we change the view to look down directly from above (`view={0}{90}`) so we get a 2D plot showing the shading. The shading is set as you want using a custom `colormap` running from `black!50` to `black!5`.

Once the 3D plot is drawn you can use your existing `\draw` commands to draw the inner and outer curves over the top. These commands must be placed within the `axis` environment so that the same coordinate system is used.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

% parameters
\def\clr{7}       % clearance
\def\pen{-6.}     % negative penetration
\def\fz{0.625}    % fake zero
\def\nl{2}        % number of lobes
\def\wl{0.18}     % width of lobes
\def\th{0.3}      % thickness

\pgfplotsset{
  colormap={greycolormap}{color=(black!50) color=(black!5)}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      view={0}{90},
      data cs=polarrad,
      domain=0.3*pi:0.7*pi,
      y domain=0:\th,
      samples=32,
      axis equal,
      hide axis,
      colormap name=greycolormap,
      declare function={
        innerring(\x)=\clr-(\clr+\pen)*exp(-((\x-(pi/\nl))/\wl)^2);
        outerring(\x)=\th+innerring(\x);
      }
    ]
    \addplot3 [surf, shader=interp]
      (x,
       {y + innerring(x)},
       y);
    \draw [line width=1.4pt, black!50, domain=0.3*pi:0.7*pi, samples=32, smooth]
      plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x r, radius={innerring(\x)});
    \draw [thick, black!50, domain=0.3*pi:0.7*pi, samples=32, smooth]
      plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x r, radius={outerring(\x)});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Nice and clear explanations, thank you :) +1

Answer (score 2):

I do not know, whether `fillbetween` can do that, but you can finetune sth. like that:

```
% Filling
\foreach \a in {0,0.01,...,0.3}{
\pgfmathsetmacro\c{35-100*\a}
\draw[Curve, red!\c] plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x r, radius= {\a+R1(\x)});
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

% packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

% parameters
\def\clr{7}       % clearance
\def\pen{-6.}     % negative penetration
\def\fz{0.625}    % fake zero
\def\nl{2}        % number of lobes
\def\wl{0.18}     % width of lobes
\def\th{0.3}      % thickness

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
R1(\x)=\clr-(\clr+\pen)*exp(-((\x - (pi/\nl))/\wl)^2));
R2(\x)=\th + \clr-(\clr+\pen)*exp(-((\x - (pi/\nl))/\wl)^2));
},
Curve/.style={
line width=1.4pt, color=black!50, domain=0.3*pi:0.7*pi, samples=256, smooth,
},
]
% Filling
\foreach[count=\n] \a in {0,0.01,...,0.3}{
\pgfmathsetmacro\c{35-100*\a}
\draw[Curve, red!\c] plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x r, radius= {\a+R1(\x)});
%\node[yshift=-\n cm] {\c};
}

% inner path A
\draw[Curve, name path=A] plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x r,radius= {R1(\x)});
% outer path B
\draw[Curve, name path=B] plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x r,radius= {R2(\x)});

%\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B]{bottom color=gray!66, top color=gray!33};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that definitely looks like what I wanted, I thought about this kind of somehow bruteforce approach like this one, I will still wait to see if there is something else that come up before accepting any answers :) +1

Comment: Maybe `declare function={  A(\x)=mod(\x, 2*pi/\nl);  }` and then `\draw[Curve, name path=A] plot ({A(\x)}:{R1(\x)});`

Comment: I recommend that you address this in a new question, with an MWE that only focuses on this part.

Comment: @cis, I notice that it doesn't work to do `radius={\th+R1(\x)}` for the second curve. Do you know why? I guess some kind of rounding error?